# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class Button

Tags: android, xml

I am facing this issue on my App start page.
This is an error of crash report from Crashlystics, I have traced it to my android xml file, but don't seem to understand why I have the error

This is the error

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sckoolboy.unilorinnet/com.example.signinfunction.Activity.StartActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class Button
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

This is my android xml buttons, i have checked the drawable file from the button as explained in most questions similar to this, but i see that mine is quite well placed as others, i do not know what exactly is being done wrong

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/unilorin_bg"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="@string/see_what_s_happening_at_the_university_of_ilorin_right_now"
        android:textColor="@color/text_main"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/createAccount"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@color/unilorin"
        android:text="@string/create_account"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/createAccount"
        android:background="@color/unilorin"
        android:text="@string/login_instead"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/createAccount2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="@string/google_sign_in"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:cornerRadius="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"/>


    <ProgressBar
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar"
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:visibility="gone"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:background="@xml/progress_bar"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my round button xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/unilorin" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="24dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="24dp"
        android:topRightRadius="24dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="24dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Can you post the `rounded_button` XML?

Comment: I have included round button xml

Comment: if you could post the full content of the layout XML, we'll figure out what is exactly at line 31.

Comment: @MeowCat2012 i have added added the full layout xml

Comment: Didn't see it. I mean the file with 3 `<Button>`s. It should also begin with "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>".

Comment: @MeowCat2012 I am sorry, I thought I updated the code, but now I have